# Why can't get the shell script's parameter count in a function

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm confused about why can't get the script's parameter count in a function, could anybody help me? thanks in advance:)

**test.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
check(){
    echo $#
    if [ $# -lt 2 ]; then
        echo "Argument missing"
        exit 1
    fi
}
echo $#
check
```

**Run:**

```
./test.sh aa bb
```

**output**:

```
2
0
```

Comment: What you describe is generally considered a feature ;-)! Just change to `check "${@}"`. Good luck.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Functions have their own local copies of the argument variables, including `$#`. They are related to the arguments of the *function*, and the equivalents at the script level are shadowed. If you want to get the script's argument variables then you will need to either store them somewhere else first or pass them to the function.

```
check "$@"
```